# How to render based on a condition in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say we have a component, with the following definition:

```
export const MentForm: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
```

It's return is a `div` with a load of HTML, some of which is the following:

```
    <div className="form">
        <MentFormButton {...fProps} />
        <FlyComp
          user={props.user}
          onClick={props.onShowFly(props.user)}
        />
        {showFlyForm (
          <FlyForm
            onFlyed={() => {
              if (props.onFlyClicked) {
                props.onFlyClicked(flies)
              }
              setShowFlyForm(false)
            }}
            onFlyFail={() => {
              setShowFlyForm(false)
            }}
            user={flies}
          />
        )}
    </div>
```

Now, when we click the button, onShowFly gets triggered

We have another TSX file that, within a `Test` functional component, there is a return with a `<div>` and that has the following:

```
      <MentForm
        user={new User}
        onCancelClick={() => {
          if (props.user) {
            wait()
          }
        }}
        onShowFly={() => {// HERE //}}
      />
```

Where I've wrote "HERE", I want to be able to have the stuff in curly braces in the `MentForm` component to activate.... but I don't know how to do this....

Answer (score 0):

Within the component that has your `showFlyForm`, you can use `useEffect` to fire off a function whenever the state changes and then just check for `showFlyForm === true` or whichever logic you use to check for showing the form.

Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
  showFlyForm && [your HERE function]
}, [showFlyForm])
```

Comment: I get `Line 51:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Comment: I'm like super super noob.... In the other page how can I check `showFlyForm` if it is out of scope and on another page?

Comment: i.e. what would also go in `onShowFly`?